anangram in react with expected output
I am new to react. I am learning by coding an anagram problem.
I am trying to display the below result in the browser.
[['silent', 'listen'], ['test'] , ['another']]
but I am seeing  this result. ---> [ "s", "i", "l", "e", "n", "t" ]
can you let me know how to display the expected result.
providing the sandbox and code below
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [words, setWords] = ["silent", "listen", "test", "another"];
  const [groupedAnangrams, setGroupedAnangrams] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const groupAnangrams = (words) => {
      const anangramGroups = {};
      const result = [];
      for (const word of words) {
        const sortedWord = word.split("").sort().join("");

        if (anangramGroups[sortedWord]) {
          anangramGroups[sortedWord].push(word);
        } else {
          anangramGroups[sortedWord] = word;
        }
      }
      for (const group in anangramGroups) {
        result.push(anangramGroups[group]);
      }

      return result;
    };

    const grouped = groupAnangrams(words);
    setGroupedAnangrams(grouped);
  }, [words]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>{JSON.stringify(groupedAnangrams, null, 2)}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}


Why are you destructuring a normal string array with const [words, setWords]? Did you forget a useState call?

(Disregarding the fact that none of those should be state at the moment.)

@unmitigated thanks for your response, sorry I forgot to include the sandbox link. Providing it here, can you please let me know how to fix it https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/266lj6?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js

@NguyenNTD thanks for your response, I made your suggested changes bur still no luck. Providing it here, can you please let me know how to fix it https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/266lj6?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js

You can try this one. It's based on your code.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [words] = useState(['silent', 'listen', 'test', 'another']); // --> diff here too
  const [groupedAnagrams, setGroupedAnagrams] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const groupAnagrams = (words) => {
      const anagramGroups = {};
      const result = [];
      
      for (const word of words) {
        const sortedWord = word.split('').sort().join('');

        if (anagramGroups[sortedWord]) {
          anagramGroups[sortedWord].push(word);
        } else {
          anagramGroups[sortedWord] = [word]; // --> diff here
        }
      }

      for (const group in anagramGroups) {
        result.push(anagramGroups[group]);
      }

      return result;
    };

    const grouped = groupAnagrams(words);
    setGroupedAnagrams(grouped);
  }, [words]);

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>{JSON.stringify(groupedAnagrams, null, 2)}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}


There are two main issues here.
First, you are not using useState correctly. But, besides that, in this case, there is no need to useState for it. That’s because you only need to receive the words property and are not using setWords.
So in this issues there are two ways to fix it:
Change your code from:
const [words, setWords] = ["silent", "listen", "test", "another"];

to:
const [words, setWords] = useState(["silent", "listen", "test", "another"]);

Or just simplify to:
const words = ["silent", "listen", "test", "another"];

Secondly, use this logic here:
anangramGroups[sortedWord] = [word];

Please make these change and you can see the correct result.

Please see below for observations, code corrections and suggestions.
A full list of the corrected code with test run results is enclosed below. It is basically your own code, the change is only in the corrected part.
a) an unintended code
The below code is de-structuring the given array and assigns the first two string values into the the two variables on the left. Therefore the variables words and setWords will have the values "silent" and "listen". This may not be the action intended over here. Therefore, please review this code and correct it to the best possible way.
const [words, setWords] = ["silent", "listen", "test", "another"];

One of the possible ways to correct the same is given below. The below code is intended to declare and initialise the variable words with the given array. Please note that the variable words over here is not a state, on the contrary, it is a local variable which does not survive a render. However it would suffice for this case. This correction will be well understood when you see below the corrected code in action.
const words = ["silent", "listen", "test", "another"];

b) review the useEffect dependency array
The following code sets the dependency array with the variable words. And it is expected that every change in the variable words should invoke useEffect. As long as the list of words is hard-coded in the component as it is in this case, this variable will not change. It will get initial values, and will remain unchanged. Therefore this dependency may be reviewed.
 useEffect(() => {
    const groupAnangrams = (words) => {
     ...
    setGroupedAnangrams(grouped);
  }, [words]);

One of the possible revisions is given below. The below code sets an empty dependency array. It means that the code inside useEffect will run only once - that will be on mounting the component or the component will appear for the first time. The objective of this revision will also be well understood when you see the code in action.
 useEffect(() => {
    const groupAnangrams = (words) => {
     ...
    setGroupedAnangrams(grouped);
  }, []);

c) a logical error
The below code, sets the word against the property. The word is a string over here. However this is not sufficient for the intended output. The output asks for it to be a string inside an array. Therefore this statement requires correction.
anangramGroups[sortedWord] = word;

The correction is this: Please enclose the string within an array. The following code does more than the previous one. The code sets a string enclosed in an array.
anangramGroups[sortedWord] = [word];

d) a cascading issue
The below code is intended to add more string values into the array. However, it will work only if the existing value is an array. Therefore the correction we applied above is very essential, it will make this code also working. Without that correction, this statement will fail as push is a method available only on arrays not on strings.
anangramGroups[sortedWord].push(word);

Corrected code - full listing
app.js
// The corrected statements have been commented 
// with line numbers as line 1, line 2 and line 3.

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const words = ['silent', 'listen', 'test', 'another']; // line 1
  const [groupedAnangrams, setGroupedAnangrams] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const groupAnangrams = (words) => {
      const anangramGroups = {};
      const result = [];
      for (const word of words) {
        const sortedWord = word.split('').sort().join('');

        if (anangramGroups[sortedWord]) {
          anangramGroups[sortedWord].push(word);
        } else {
          anangramGroups[sortedWord] = [word]; // line 3
        }
      }
      for (const group in anangramGroups) {
        result.push(anangramGroups[group]);
      }

      return result;
    };

    const grouped = groupAnangrams(words);
    setGroupedAnangrams(grouped);
  }, []); // line 2
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>{JSON.stringify(groupedAnangrams, null, 2)}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

Test run
Application on loaded state

